# Dockerfile chown is being overwritten

Tags: docker, file, chown

I am installing `newrelic` php agent in a customer dockerfile executing nginx and php-fpm.
The dwefault user and group running are `www-data`

I am creating the logs dir for newrelic and chowning to www-data, but when container starts owner is still root if i `ls -l /var/log/newrelic` and this causes newrelic to not work

Keep in mind that I am not mounting in docker-compose any volume later, so /var/log/newrelic is not overriden with anything.

So in current status after building image with below dockerfile, then creating container, using shell inside and checking stats result is wrong like this:

```
/var/www/html/app # ls -l /var/log/newrelic/
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           215 Jul 19 16:35 newrelic-daemon.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1081 Jul 19 16:35 php_agent.log
```

Should be www-data for user and group instead of root

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM kristijorgji/php-fpm-8-nginx:0.0.3 as base

FROM base as builder

# we are not installing js or php dependencies here as those shoud have been done before in previous scripts
# just copying files

COPY . /var/www/html/app/

FROM base as production

ARG BUILD_ENV
ARG NEWRELIC_LICENCE
ARG NEWRELIC_PROJECT_NAME=w-${BUILD_ENV}

RUN test -n "$BUILD_ENV" || (echo "BUILD_ENV  not set" && false)

# have to switch to root user temporary as newrelic install script runs only as root
USER root
# Install newrelic agent
RUN nr_version=newrelic-php5-9.17.1.301-linux-musl \
    && curl -o ${nr_version}.tar.gz https://download.newrelic.com/php_agent/release/${nr_version}.tar.gz \
    && gzip -dc ${nr_version}.tar.gz | tar xf - \
    && cd ${nr_version} \
    && NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 ./newrelic-install install
RUN nr_logs=/var/log/newrelic && mkdir -p "$nr_logs" && chown -R www-data.www-data "$nr_logs"
COPY ./docker-data /docker-data
# setup the licence
RUN nrinipath=$(php -r "echo(PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR);")/newrelic.ini \
    && cp /docker-data/newrelic.ini $nrinipath \
    && sed -i -e "s/REPLACE_WITH_REAL_KEY/${NEWRELIC_LICENCE}/" \
    -e "s/REPLACE_WITH_REAL_APP_NAME/${NEWRELIC_PROJECT_NAME}/" \
    $nrinipath
USER www-data

COPY --from=builder --chown=www-data /var/www/html/app/ /var/www/html/app/
WORKDIR /var/www/html/app/
```

If you want to check dockerfile of base image kristijorgji/php-fpm-8-nginx:0.0.3 here is the file:
https://github.com/kristijorgji/docker-images/blob/main/php-fpm-8-nginx/Dockerfile

**Steps to reproduce issue are very easy:**
First create one empty folder and copy the given dockerfile then just build image and run a container to check folder permissions

1. Build the image `docker build --build-arg BUILD_ENV=production \ --build-arg NEWRELIC_LICENCE=doesntmatter \ -t mytag .`
2. Create container from image to check folder `docker run --rm -it -u root --entrypoint='' /bin/sh mytag`
3. inside container run `ls -l /var/log/newrelic` and will see root:root are owners instead of www-data:www-data

PS:
Solution here is to change ownership of /var/log/newrelic to www-data if i do this in live executing container newrelic agent work, but i want to automate this so log folder is coming prebacked with right permissions since dockerfile

Comment: What user is the process running as?  Does the ownership of the directory itself change (`ls -ld /var/log/newrelic`)? Your base image is set up to run supervisor; can you instead run one process to a container without that?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't know what user is running newrelic process. I know that container runs as `www-data` user as we can see from the dockerfile. So `docker run` or docker-compose starts as www-data

Comment: I run the command ls -ld and I see www-data, with just ls -l see root:root, here output ```/var/www/html/app # ls -l /var/log/newrelic
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           215 Jul 19 16:35 newrelic-daemon.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1081 Jul 19 16:35 php_agent.log
/var/www/html/app # ls -ld /var/log/newrelic
drwxr-xr-x    1 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 19 16:35 /var/log/newrelic
/var/www/html/app # 
```

Comment: That says to me that the chown(1) call is working correctly, but the process writing the files is running as root.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can fix the newrelic to work fine by running this command inside the started container: `chown -R www-data.www-data /var/log/newrelic/ && sh /etc/init.d/php-fpm8 reload && nginx -s reload`  But I want to automate the fix inside dockerfile so all is prepared correctly. I am not sure why this error happen, I contacted newrelic team and they said that agent does not run as `root`. Docker container runs as www-data user, but the log files from newrelic are created as root that is weird...